# Feeding a variable in a function with data from other part of html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

that i would like to do is the following:

1. Call data via json feed on a part of html page, especially into a div.
2. Get the result from (1) and place it into a new variable of a function, in order to update the data of this function

So, i have a json function that is usually used in blogger platforms.

```
function new22(json) {
    var htmlcode ='';
    document.write( htmlcode );
    for ( var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++ ) {
        for ( var j = 0; j < json.feed.entry[ i ].link.length; j++ ) {
            if ( json.feed.entry[ i ].link[ j ].rel == 'alternate' ) {
                var postUrl = json.feed.entry[ i ].link[ j ].href;
                break;
            }
        }
        var postTitle = json.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
        var postThumbSize = 600;
        var postThumb = json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url;
        postThumb = postThumb.replace( '/s72-c/', '/s' + postThumbSize + '/' );
        var postCategory = json.feed.entry[i].category[0].term;
        var item = "[locationData('test.html', '___', '___', '_____', "1327 Intervale Ave, Bronx, NY ", "+38099231212", "5", "27"), 40.72956781, -73.99726866, 0, markerIcon],";
        htmlcode += '';
        document.write(item);
    }
}
```

In the previous function, i can replace static values, for example "test.html" with "+postTitle+","postCategory" and so on, in relation with blogger posts that i've published for specific post label....

This function, i could call it with following javascript, place it for example into a div, for example ....

```
<div id="123">
<script>
document.write(&quot;&lt;script src=\&quot;/feeds/posts/summary/-/<data:content/>?max-results=4&amp;orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=favouritePosts\&quot;&gt;&lt;\/script&gt;&quot;);
                            </script></div>
```

When html page is loading, as result of this javascript will be (2)

```
[locationData('bloggerpost1', '___', '___', '_____', "1327 Intervale Ave, Bronx, NY ", "+38099231212", "5", "27"), 40.72956781, -73.99726866, 0, markerIcon],locationData('bloggerpost2', '___', '___', '_____', "1327 Intervale Ave, Bronx, NY ", "+38099231212", "5", "27"), 40.72956781, -73.99726866, 0, markerIcon],].....
```

Ok, until this point all are good and easy.
But the following is a heavy headache....

Into a google map function, could i get the previous (2) result and update a specific variable of this function?
Especially, there is the following function, that is related with google maps

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    var markerIcon = {
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 16),
        url: 'images/marker.png',
    }

function mainMap() {
        function locationData(locationURL, locationCategory, locationImg, locationTitle, locationAddress, locationPhone, locationStarRating, locationRevievsCounter) {
            return ('<div class="map-popup-wrap"><div class="map-popup"><div class="infoBox-close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div class="map-popup-category">' + locationCategory + '</div><a href="' + locationURL + '" class="listing-img-content fl-wrap"><img src="' + locationImg + '" alt=""></a> <div class="listing-content fl-wrap"><div class="card-popup-raining map-card-rainting" data-staRrating="' + locationStarRating + '"><span class="map-popup-reviews-count">( ' + locationRevievsCounter + ' reviews )</span></div><div class="listing-title fl-wrap"><h4><a href=' + locationURL + '>' + locationTitle + '</a></h4><span class="map-popup-location-info"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>' + locationAddress + '</span><span class="map-popup-location-phone"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>' + locationPhone + '</span></div></div></div></div>')
        }

var locations=[[locationData('test.html', '___', '___', '_____', "1327 Intervale Ave, Bronx, NY ", "+38099231212", "5", "27"), 40.72956781, -73.99726866, 0, markerIcon],[locationData('listing-single.html', 'Conference and Events', 'images/all/1.jpg', 'Event In City Mol', "W 85th St, New York, NY ", "+38099231212", "4", "5"), 40.76221766, -73.96511769, 1, markerIcon]];
```

The main map function has a variable with name "locations", in which there is a specific form, how to insert a point of interest into a google map.

So, that i want to do is, if is it possible, depends on blogger posts with specific label, to create via json feed, a total of "[locationData('test.html', '***', '***', '_____', "1327 Intervale Ave, Bronx, NY ", "+38099231212", "5", "27"), 40.72956781, -73.99726866, 0, markerIcon]," elements.

that will be the important information for google map function into variable locations. I dont know if it's possible. The first thing that i have done is

```
var location= document.getElementById("123").innerHTML;

var locations= "["+location+"];";
```

but it's not working. The google map is empty, without any point of interest. Any help?????
Thanks for your time.....

Comment: I do get your idea. However, if you could share a minimal jsfiddle with code stumps & whatever works so far, it would help improve my answer!

Comment: I have a test blogger site for this...If you want, give me an email to make you administrator in order to have access on what i have done until now....